# How to draw A LOT of polygons on google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a map that highlights over 2 dozen regions on a google map via coordinates.  It seems i'm hitting the query string limit.

Any suggestions as to a work around?

Thanks in advance for all/any recommendations.

---

Thank you for the comments.  I lost track of this post and didn't get a chance to test out your solutions.

The image attached below is what I was trying to fill out.

My polygons are region groupings and i'm trying to color code them.

```
{
    where: "Members in("+arrGrpOne+")",
        polygonOptions:{
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity : .5
        }
},{
    where: "Members in ("+arrGrpTwo+")",
        polygonOptions:{
            fillColor: '#FF00FF',
            fillOpacity : .5
}
```

If i add more where clause i get the following error :
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) 
https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US&lyrs=ft%3A115hPQ0BVPioObq47a…vwwtvt,twtuuwvwwtvv&z=12&src=apiv3&xc=1&callback=*xdc*._d9mcoj&token=25665

Comment: What's the query string limit?  How long's your string?  What does it look like? (maybe don't post the entire thing here, enough to give us an idea what you're up to)

Comment: For _lots_ of polygons use something that renders them with tiles (KmlLayer, FusionTablesLayer).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex your polygons are you may be able to use encoded polylines:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1#EncodedPolylines

Try and recreate your polygon with the [interactive encoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility).

[GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=polyline%20encoder) should have several libraries available depending on your application.